# Strange bug with ng-repeat and filter

Tags: angularjs, node.js, mongodb

I'm using NodeJS, ANgularJS, and MongoDB with mongoose

Here is my model :

```
var PostSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    nomReseau : String,
    corps : String,
    etat : String,
    section : String
});
```

I got a function that change the attribute etat:

```
$scope.passer = function(index){
    var post = $scope.posts[index];
    post.etat = "enCours";
    Posts.update({id: post._id}, post);
    $scope.editing[index] = false;
}
```

I'm using a ng-repeat for show object in my database :

```
<ul>
    <li ng-repeat="post in posts ">
        <p>
            <a ng-show="!editing[$index]" href="#/{{post._id}}">{{post.corps}}</a>
        </p>
        <button ng-show="!editing[$index]" ng-click="passer($index)">Passer</button>
    </li>
</ul>
```

I can see all post in my database and when I click on the button this works perfectly the attribute etat change and all is fine.

But when I add a filter in the ng-repeat like this :

```
<li ng-repeat="post in posts | filter:{ etat:'aTraiter'} ">
```

The filter works great I have all post with the attribute etat:'aTraiter'

But if I click on my previous button and change the attribute etat nothing change and I try with other functions they all work wihout the filter but when I put it nothing work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that `$index` will change if less data is shown (because you're filtering). you could use directly `post` variable

```
ng-click="passer(post)"
```

and your function should be something like

```
$scope.passer = function(post){
    post.etat = "enCours";
    Posts.update({id: post._id}, post);
    var index = $scope.posts.findIndex(function(p) { /* comparison to get original index */ }); /* keep in mind findIndex is not supported on IE, you might want to use filter or for loop instead) */
    $scope.editing[index] = false;
}
```

you could handle editing in the post variable directly. So in your passer function you can do this

```
post.editing = false;
```

and in your view

```
ng-show="!post.editing"
```

this way you won't use `$index` and you will prevent all issues with being updated by filters

Answer (score 0):

Do you have any controllers/services that access `$scope.editing`? If so, you might be setting the `$scope.editing[$index]` equal a previous state where it wasn't equal to false. You may also want to consider that you are assuming `$scope.editing[$index]` is going to be a boolean. if it has any other type such as string or number then it will evaluate to true.

**Otherwise** none of your results have the attribute etat equal to 'aTraiter' so they aren't showing. Have you verified that any of them actually do have etat equal to 'aTraiter'. You might be changing that value somewhere else. Possibly from the Passer function

Comment: yes I have controller everything works, and all post with the attribute etat equal to 'aTraiter'  are showing.

It's just when I put the filter it's just the functions who doesn't work, but the visual is great.

Comment: Try debugging by adding something which will display the etat attribute and the value of $scope.editing[$index]. Then remove the filter and run the program. After you press the previous button look at their values and see if that's what you expected them to be.

Answer (score 0):

There are bugs in AngularJS v1.4 where in certain situations the ng-repeat breaks. I upgraded to v1.6 and it went away.